# I want to view logs of users/service account who has accessed the Bigquery dataset & table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the table of audit logs i.e "cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access" I want to extract from this table, the username/serviceaccount email , the timestamp of when the table was accessed or queried,dataset name, & the table which was accessed or query was run. I want this information. I tried writing a query but I am getting jobIDs/datasetids for general queries and not dataset names but if a user runs a "create" query then I can see the dataset name and tablename. I got timestamp and user as output but I am facing issues in datasetname and table name.

I have used this

```
SELECT

timestamp,

protopayload auditlog.authenticationInfo.principal Email as user,

protopayload auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobQueryDoneResponse.job.jobConfiguration.query as query,

protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_vi_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable datasetID as dataset, protopayload auditlog.servicedata_vi_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable tableID as table,



From `shaker.jack.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access`

Order by timestamp DESC
```

After using this query I am getting datasetname and tablename just when the user is using "create" query for other queries I am getting random I'ds. I need the names for all the queries the user used or accessed data. Kindly help with that.